# My network Bridge is stuck enalbed, and I see the ethernet icon on taskbar

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet, taskbar

recently I bridged my wifi with my ethernet connection, so I could access internet on my XP computer, however when the XP computer died (*An XP computer died? This is unheard of!*), I went to remove the ethernet from the bridge, and it said `"An unexpected error occurred when configuring network bridge."`. It says that whenever I attempt to remove the wifi or the wired connection from the bridge. **I also constantly see the wired connection Icon instead of the wifi icon on the taskbar**. This is annoying because I am unable to see my wireless network's strength. I have not changed any network registry settings, and **I really wish to refrain from resetting my Computer**. It is shared and it has many paid programs on it that we no longer have the keys for. ***Thank you for your time!*** 
-Lucas.

P.S. I am also experiencing a few `IP address conflict` errors with my computer, don't know if this is related. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (not enough rep) so here's an answer. Have you tried deleting the network bridge itself? Right click its icon in the Network Adapters folder and click delete/remove.

IP address conflict *can* indicate an intruder on your wireless network sharing your MAC address. Check to see whether it goes away when you remove the bridge, otherwise post again :)